# UIWebView scrollView changed it content offset when status bar hides

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios7-statusbar

I have a view in my app (iOS7) where a have such a `view controllers` hierarchy `ViewController`->`childViewController`->`childViewController`->`myChildViewController`. 
`myChildViewController` has a full sized `UIWebView` on it. I have a `UIButton` to hide `UIToolBar` from one of `childViewControlle`r. When I press the button - `UIWebView` `scrollView` changed its `content offset` by `status bar` hide. How to avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

Previously mentioned solution works just fine.

```
[self addSubview:webView];
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

That should only happen if you've made the `UIWebView` the main view, such as

```
viewController.view = webView;
```

If you make it a subview instead, it should ignore the offsets:

```
webView.frame = viewController.view.bounds;
webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight
[viewController.view addSubview:webView];
```

It may also change if the parent view controller is resized...

Another thing you can try in the view controller that holds the web view:

```
[viewController setAutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets:NO];
```

Comment: My 'UIWebView' is not a 'myViewController.view' it's on 'myViewController.view.contentView'. I tried to set "automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets" to 'NO' but that didn't work for me.

Comment: What's the type of the view controller?

Comment: 'UIViewController'->'UINavigationContoroller'->'UIViewController'->'MyViewController with UIWebView'

Comment: As far as I know, `UIView` doesn't have a `contentView` property... What's the superclass of your `MyViewController`?

Comment: Yes. `UIViewController` doesn't have `contentView` property. It's a simple `UIView` instance above `self.view` in `UIViewController`. It is used for simple size manage via margin. But I checked the size and tried to remove all margins from it. That didn't help.